# sending HTML as an attachment in Java/Spring

Tags: java, javascript, html, email, spring-mvc

I have an HTML document that I get with

```
 document.body.innerHTML
```

How to attach this HTML to an email? I want to send this HTML file as an attachment in java/Spring

Comment: Submit a pseudo `<form>` with this value and then just grab it in the Request handler...

Comment: @lan thanks for the comment, could you elaborate with some pseudo code.

Comment: Well, say you have a `<form id="main_form" action="" method="POST"></form>` and inside of it, you have `<input type="hidden" id="the_doc" name="the_doc" value="" />`. When you're ready to submit the information, you can use `document.getElementById("the_doc").value = document.body.innerHTML; document.getElementById("main_form").submit();`. Then, in your Controller, you just need to have your method accept one parameter, "the_doc". Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks lan, this is how i tried but it throws exception at the server side,

Comment: Can you explain/show exactly what you're doing on the server (and your Javascript/HTML too)? And what Exception is being thrown?

Comment: @Dom when you suggest an edit be sure to take care of **all** the issues in the post. Compare your edit (typo in title) to the one that followed. I voted to reject your edit as too minor and you run the risk of rejected edits when you leave so many issues unadddressed.

Comment: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "">" is the exception i get lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: with a server**

If you want to send it to the same server that hosts the HTML file, it is very easy using an ajax call.

For example if you use JQuery, it can be done with:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',//or 'GET' depending on how your server is listening
  url: 'the url to your server page',
  data: data
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

If the HTML was loaded from local hard disk in the browser or if you want to send the HTML to a host, you should be looking for cross-domain ajax requests.

Depending on your application, you might want to [*sanitize*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) the HTML and send it with an Ajax request.

**Method 2: Without a server**

If you want to make a link on the screen which allows the user to send an email with the body that you specify, you can use an anchor tag with `mailto`. Please remember to encode the text:

```
$('<a href="mailto:myemail@myserver.com?subject=This+is+the+data&body='
+ encodeURI($( '#some-text' ).text())
+ '">Send</a>' );
```

[Here is a JSfiddle for you to try](http://jsfiddle.net/dRYLA/).